# GOCD fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD'

Tags: git, bash, continuous-delivery, go-cd

Wondering if anyone can help with the following error I'm getting back attempting to run a GOCD pipeline.

The Go Server is installed on a Mac mini and I have a Go Agent running on a Windows machine.

I have Source Tree and Git for Windows installed. Using Source Tree or Git Bash, I am able to operate Git as normal without any issues.

Yet when the Go Agent attempts to run a pipeline I am getting the following error

```
11:58:46.723 [go] Job Started: 2017-07-06 11:58:46 BST

11:58:46.723 [go] Start to prepare TestPipeline/10/build/7/build on WinBuildMachine [C:\Program Files (x86)\Go Agent]
11:58:46.754 [go] Start to update materials.

11:58:46.754 [go] Start updating files at revision XXXXXX from https://github.com/X/X.git
11:58:46.785 Error performing command: --- Command ---
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
--- Environment ---
{}
--- INPUT ----


--OUTPUT ---
HEAD
--- ERROR ---
STDERR: fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
STDERR: Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
STDERR: 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
---

11:58:46.832 [go] Job completed TestPipeline/10/build/7/build on WinBuildMachine [C:\Program Files (x86)\Go Agent]
```

I'm short of ideas so any help would be appreciated.

**PROGRESS UPDATE**

I've setup full control permissions for the Go Agents sandbox and I am not getting the following error

```
12:47:49.339 [go] Job Started: 2017-07-06 12:47:49 BST

12:47:49.339 [go] Start to prepare TestPipeline/10/build/9/build on WinBuildMachine [C:\Program Files (x86)\Go Agent]
12:47:49.355 [go] Start to update materials.

12:47:49.355 [go] Start updating files at revision XXXXX from https://github.com/XXXXX/XXXXX.git
12:47:49.402 [GIT] Fetching changes
12:47:49.996 STDERR: bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
```

Go cancelled this job as it has not generated any console output for more than 20 minute(s)

The Git Bash directory has a /tmp folder so I'm unsure on what this is referring too.

Again any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the permissions on this `/tmp` folder ?   `ls -ld /tmp`

Comment: The /tmp in the Git directory, C:\Program Files\Git,has the following permissions `drwxr-xr-x 1 Build User 197121 0 Jul 6 12:24 /tmp/`